# Bootstrap dropdown-menu appearance

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know what I am looking for, but when pressing an item, the two others changes for a black background, I can't figure out which rule is applied on those two "not pressed items".

I tried setting active / focus states on the pressed element but had nothing to do with it.

It's a simple bootstrap 3 menu built with the following code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">   
    <li>
        <a class="user-display-name" href="/galaxy/profile">Pascal Lalonde</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-current-locale="en" href="/galaxy/repos?locale=fr">FR</a></li>
    <li class="open">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/galaxy/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><i class="fa fa-caret-down borderless"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="/galaxy/repos">Repository</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/galaxy/tdp">TDP</a></li>
            <li><a href="/galaxy/rk">RK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is it I am missing?

Here's the screenshot of the behavior:

[image]

[EDIT]

I am being asked to provide sample CSS code, but if I could, this would mean that I'd already have my answer. I don't know what I am looking for.

I am trying to debug the behavior so I can find what is causing this to happen.

Thing is this happens only when I actually press on the "TDP" option, I cannot debug in the console while "pressing" on the item, because a click triggers the link to continue.

So my question here, is what kind of CSS rule could be applied when an item is pressed? If nothing is there, would this mean that Bootstrap actually execute something when pressing on it? It tried looking at the dropdown javascript code, did not see anything like it.

[EDIT #2]

Just realized this happens in the template I am using.
Click [here](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07JN5T9) to see. 
Choose the user option in the top right menu and then just "press" any of the shown options. All others will be displayed black.

[EDIT #3]

It seems the other elements gets "activated" while pressing the other menu options, this causing the background of the not-pressed items of the menu to change. I still don't understand why forcing the :active state through the browser doesn't apply the css rules, but this fixed what I "don't understand yet"

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu:active {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that you have some custom CSS as well? I think you will need to include that in the question as well.

Comment: I am actually looking for a css rule that would trigger the change on the "not pressed" items, not the actual css values

Comment: Can recreate the issue in -> https://jsfiddle.net/ otherwise I doubt anyone can help you with this one.

Answer (score -1):

As said by Schmalzy you have a custom CSS it would be nice if you can include that in the question.

Or you can try to change .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover { background-color: transparent; }

Let me if that helps

Comment: This isn't really an answer so much as a request for more information. As a result, it's better left as a comment.

Comment: Why you gave negative he has not pasted the complete question? Do you have any idea what bootstrap is? He is talking about caret hover option, you fool

Comment: The answer section is for answers, not requests for more information. I recommend you also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Let him say that it is wrong, I will delete it myself

Comment: Agreed that only the OP can tell if your suggested CSS will work. But it also depends on where he inserts your fix. It's difficult to give good guidance without his custom CSS, which is why I believe this is ultimately just a shot in the dark and a request for more information. Again, please see the link for answer guidelines.

Comment: I read it, let him say it is wrong and I will delete it. I didn't mean to be rude but that was a very quick negative on your part

Comment: It was in the review queue for first posts, and I honestly think it's not a very high quality answer. Granted, the OP's not looking for the bible here, but I don't think there's enough information to give an intelligent response yet.